# why yowsup can not able to send request to whatsapp server?

Tags: python, whatsapp, yowsup

`Yowsup` was running flawlessly yesterday...and today it's giving me an error.
I just download `Yowsup` from https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup and edit config.example file for change number and country code then fire below command in terminal

```
python ./yowsup-cli -c config.example -d --requestcode sms
```

To send request code. Please guess what could be problem?

```
erp@erp-desktop:~/Downloads/yowsup-master/src$ python ./yowsup-cli -c config.example -d --requestcode sms
{'Accept': 'text/json', 'User-Agent': 'WhatsApp/2.11.1 S40Version/14.26 Device/Nokia302'}
cc=91&in=9033308076&lc=US&lg=en&mcc=000&mnc=000&method=sms&id=f1b708bba17f1ce948dc979f4d7092bc&token=6ee7d82a64bb51c6f8742f30a245c7ef
Opening connection to v.whatsapp.net
Sending GET request to /v2/code?cc=91&in=9033308076&lc=US&lg=en&mcc=000&mnc=000&method=sms&id=f1b708bba17f1ce948dc979f4d7092bc&token=6ee7d82a64bb51c6f8742f30a245c7ef
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./yowsup-cli", line 275, in <module>
    result = wc.send()
  File "/home/erp/Downloads/yowsup-master/src/Yowsup/Registration/v2/coderequest.py", line 60, in send
    res = super(WACodeRequest, self).send(parser)
  File "/home/erp/Downloads/yowsup-master/src/Yowsup/Common/Http/warequest.py", line 100, in send
    return self.sendGetRequest(parser)
  File "/home/erp/Downloads/yowsup-master/src/Yowsup/Common/Http/warequest.py", line 137, in sendGetRequest
    self.response = WARequest.sendRequest(host, port, path, headers, params, "GET")
  File "/home/erp/Downloads/yowsup-master/src/Yowsup/Common/Http/warequest.py", line 194, in sendRequest
    conn.request(reqType, path, params, headers);
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 958, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 992, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 954, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 814, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 776, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1161, in connect
    self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 381, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 143, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 305, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: The exception says it all: "Connection reset by peer". So the server you're trying to connect to refuses your request. Are you sure it's the right server URL?

Comment: i am using yowsup api to connect whatsapp server. i think yowsup api not able to connect to whatsapp server.